# Azure B2C event logging - Is it possible to log when customer sign-outs the same way as it's possible to see sing-ins in the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible with some custom configuration to be able to see customer sign-outs with date and time the same way it is possible to see sign-ins in OOB Azure B2C solution in Azure Portal?
[image]

I would be greatly appreciate for any hints how to achieve this as there is very little or none articles on the internet touching this matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no custom configuration available to see the sign-out logs in azure portal. as you mentioned we can see sign-in logs and audit logs.
You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs) about azure AD logs.